# Leaflet R derivePolygons missing lat missing long

Tags: r, dataframe, leaflet, rgdal

I am trying to plot the site of some disease-events data on a map.

I use this to import the data:

```
ByTown<-readOGR(dsn="C:/temp/lyme/Towns", layer="Towns", encoding = "UTF-8", verbose= FALSE)
```

check the class:

```
class(ByTown)
#getting this result
[1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
```

Then I convert all of the factors to character data and check to see that I still have a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` using `class` again, which I do:

Then I format the data I wish to merge into the same title case as the original:

```
townCount$City<-str_to_title(townCount$City)
```

Then I geo_join the count data to the spatial polygon data frame:

```
ByTown<-geo_join(ByTown, townCount,"MCD_NAME", "City")
```

Then I set the palette and run the mapping:

```
pal = colorQuantile("PuOr",ByTown$count, n=5 )
map<-leaflet(ByTown) %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron")%>%
  addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal(count),
            color = "#000000",
            stroke = TRUE,
            weight = 1,
            smoothFactor = 0.5,
            options(viewer = NULL))
map
```

And I get this error:

```
Error in derivePolygons(data, lng, lat, missing(lng), missing(lat), "addPolygons") : 
  addPolygons must be called with both lng and lat, or with neither.
```

I have looked in the coordinates slots and there is data in there...I am baffled by the error and not finding any useful answers online. Here is the head of the first polygon in coordinates slot:

```
head(nByTown@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords )

           [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 1036519 916318.7
[2,] 1036039 916355.8
[3,] 1031757 916299.7
[4,] 1027474 916244.5
[5,] 1026709 916198.1
[6,] 1026826 916248.3
```

Any one every have this issue, identify the root cause and fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `addPolygons` function either requires you to define the columns of latitude & longitude, OR it will try and derive them from the data you provide.

Given you haven't specified the lat/lon columns, it tries to work out which ones they are. In your case, it couldn't find them. This is mainly due to your data not being in lat/lon format.

Therefore, you'll need to transform your data to use a lat/lon projection, something like (untested)

```
nByTown_latlon <- spTransform(nByTown, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
```

Comment: Thanks..we have been using these shape files for a while and this is the first time I have had this happen. I will try that tonight and see how it goes. Thank you!

Comment: that's actually surprising: leaflet require lat/lon coordinates

Comment: I just looked, this is the first time I geo_joined without another shapefile and projection. I simply never noticed that all our other shapefiles had lat lon and when I used spTransorm to get them on in the same projection it must have fixed this shape file too...ah geoGods! So much happening under the hood!

Comment: Saved my sanity! Thank you SO MUCH!

Comment: can you please specify what packages the `spTransform` and `CRS` functions are from? `sp`? `rgdal`?

Comment: @lauren.marietta they are both from `sp`

Answer (score 23):

Don't forget to add the `data = ...` variable name in `addPolygons()` if you don't provide it in the `leaflet()` call.
I received the same error and spent hours looking for a solution :(.

This does **not** work:

```
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(ByTown)
```

and returns:

```
Error in derivePolygons(data, lng, lat, missing(lng), missing(lat), "addPolygons") : 
  addPolygons must be called with both lng and lat, or with neither.
```

This works:

```
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(data = ByTown)
```

Comment: because it was included in `leaflet(ByTown) %>%` it is passed on through the remainder of the mapping profile...

Comment: yes, I mention 'Don't forget it if you don't provide it in the `leaflet()` call'. I added this answer here because people getting the same error will likely end up looking to this page.

Comment: thanks Lennert - I was trying to map some police beats which were in an sf object.

Did not work:
    `leaflet() %>% addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldGrayCanvas) %>% addPolygons(beats)`

did work:

    `leaflet() %>% addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldGrayCanvas) %>% addPolygons(data = beats)`