# How to convert coordinates into a recognizable measurement for leaflet maps?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, gis, coordinate-transformation

I am new to the mapping functions in **R** and related packages, so any help is welcomed. Here is what I am doing, I am using ***leaflet*** in a dashboard I created through ***shiny***. I am trying to map the data I have but leaflet doesn't recognize it because the measurement of my lat and long data is in feet and not **decimal degrees** (ex: x = 33.867022, y = -112.1409750).

I know I have lat and long data in feet measurement (ex: x = 632086.70, y = 1043211.35) because I was easily able to map this in ArcMap by simply using the 
"display xy" function. Then I was able to convert the measurement format by using the "calculate geometry" function to transform from feet to a decimal degrees measurement. I am trying to automate my maps and would prefer NOT to use ArcMap for this conversion as I would like to stay in one platform (R).

My potential options (I think) and therefore questions are as follows:

**1.** Convert my data into something leaflet can recognize. Would anyone know the code, steps and/or package I need to use to convert the measurement of my lat and long data from feet to decimal degrees?

**2.** Tell leaflet to read my data in a different measurement. Is there a way (code, package, etc) to tell leaflet to read my points in feet measurement rather than decimal degrees?

**Or any other suggestions???**

Comment: What object are you trying to plot, is it a `data.frame`, or a `spatial*` object? If it's a spatial object you can use the `sp::spTransform()` function - [example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42237590/5977215)

Comment: It's a `data.frame`

Comment: Ok, so your question now becomes, 'how do I convert a data.frame of coordinates to lat/lon'. There are a few exmples on StackOverflow on how to do this. If you still are stuck, re-write your question giving an example of your data and the attempts you've made.

Comment: However, you may be able to go down your option 2 route depending on how are you getting the data into R?

Comment: What's the map's CRS (coordinate reference system)?? "Feet measurement" is too broad, and you need to be aware of the CRS in order to project the coordinates into EPSG:4326 (lat-lng equirectangular). Once you know that, have a look at [proj4 for R](http://www.rforge.net/proj4/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the help provided... My co-worker figured it out, we used the code below.

```
proj4string(d) <- CRS("+proj=tmerc +lat_0=31+lon_0=-111.9166666666667+k=0.9999 +x_0=213360 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83+to_meter=0.3048006096012192+no_defs")
CRS.new <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326") # WGS 84
d.ch102650 <- spTransform(d, CRS.new)
```

@IvanSanchez the CRS comment was helpful.