# AddPolygons() requires coordinates from SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm having troubles with Leaflet.

The following function works fine, but when I want to add markers I get an error telling me to call the longitude and latitude variables.

Works fine:

```
leaflet(mapdata) %>%
    addPolygons(color = "#444444", weight = 1, smoothFactor = 0.5,
    opacity = 1.0, fillOpacity = 0.5,
    highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "white", weight = 2,
    bringToFront = TRUE))
```

Does not work fine:

```
leaflet(mapdata) %>%
    addPolygons(color = "#444444", weight = 1, smoothFactor = 0.5,
    opacity = 1.0, fillOpacity = 0.5,
    highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "white", weight = 2,
    bringToFront = TRUE),
    addMarkers(data='coordinates', lng = longitude, lat = ~ latitude))
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Error in derivePolygons(data, lng, lat, missing(lng), missing(lat), "addPolygons") : 
addPolygons must be called with both lng and lat, or with neither
```

I used GADM to get my map data:

```
mapdata <- getData('GADM', country='NL', level=1)
```

The coordinates for a specific province can be found in the following way, but I do not know how to add all coordinates to the function:

```
head(mapdata@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords)

         [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 6.501305 53.19841
[2,] 6.504287 53.19749
[3,] 6.504779 53.19761
[4,] 6.514869 53.20009
[5,] 6.522253 53.19825
[6,] 6.523739 53.19736
```

I kind of found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237530/leaflet-r-derivepolygons-missing-lat-missing-long). They tell me to transform my data using the following function:

```
mapdata_latlon <- spTransform(mapdata, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
```

But I get the same error when I use the transformed data.

Can someone help me out here please? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it. Apparently, I was adding `addMarkers()` the wrong way.

Correct code:

```
leaflet(mapdata) %>%
    addPolygons(color = "#444444", weight = 1, smoothFactor = 0.5,
            opacity = 1.0, fillOpacity = 0.5,
                highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "white", weight = 2,
                bringToFront = TRUE)) %>%
    addMarkers(data = coordinates, lng = ~ longitude, lat = ~ latitude)
```